# XBEE Duplex Communication

Tags: embedded, xbee

I want to configure my Xbees in such a way that both of them can receive and also transmit data ?

I have two Xbee S1 modules. One is currently configured as receiver and the other as transmitter. At certain times, I want the receiver module to transmit data as well.

Could anyone give a link to a tutorial which shows how this can be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do that.  If you have them configured with "AT mode" software, you just need to set the DH and DL parameters on XBee A to the SH and SL values from XBee B, and vice-versa (B.DH = A.SH, B.DL = A.SL).

Now any characters going in the serial port on A will come out the serial port on B, and any that come in on B will go out on A.

Comment: Yes I've indeed configured them in AT Mode. Thanks a ton for the help Sir !